# What is .NET Core equivalent of Node Cluster?

Tags: node.js, .net-core

Node has a [cluster lib](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) that allows the application to start with more threads. In the example it creates a fork for each CPU.

How can I do the same in .NET Core? How can I set the number of threads/clusters my application starts with?

Answer (score 2):

## Task Parallel Library

> .NET Framework 4 introduced Task Parallel Library (TPL) as the
> preferred set of APIs for writing concurrent code. The same programming model is adopted by .NET Core.

To run a piece of code in the background, you need to wrap it into a task:

```
var backgroundTask = Task.Run(() => DoComplexCalculation(42));
// do other work
var result = backgroundTask.Result;
```

[View Article : **Multithreaded Concurrent Programming in .NET Core**](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/dotnet/1360/concurrent-programming-dotnet-core)

You could set up your slaves as tasks, spawning a task/cpu would easy.

[Learn More : **Parallel Processing and Concurrency in the .NET Framework**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-processing-and-concurrency)

[**Official .NET Core API** (search for keyword : 'parallel')](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/index?view=netcore-2.0&term=parallel)

Answer (score 2):

That Node Cluster library seems like a hack to fix nonexistence of JavaScript's of multithreading.

.NET/C# have no such problem. Your application can use as many threads as it wants. It can create and destroy threads during application's lifetime. It makes threading much easier and flexible than just starting the application for each logical CPU.

There is [full documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/threading/) along with [lots of other resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/multithreading+c%23?sort=votes&pageSize=50).